# Can "big thing" be used ironically?

Tags: meaning

> All jokes aside, Shirene Sadia from the series The Kuchursingh Family
>   is an excellent comedic actress.
>
> Sadia, who plays old woman Janjhatia on the series, orhni and all,
>   aired on Gayelle The Channel, is actually an energetic 22-year-old.
>
> The San Francique resident writes the script for the series and, for
>   the last six years, she has even found the time to act in other
>   productions.
>
> And talk about versatility: Sadia has acted as a prostitute, a vagrant
>   and other characters, saying, “there are many moods to me.”
>
> Shirene Sadia in the character as Janjhatia stands between her two
>   cast members at a family day.
>
> Sadia, who was amusing for the entire interview, described herself as
>   effervescent.
>
> Currently pursuing a practitioner’s certificate in drama and theatre
>   arts in education, Sadia said drama came naturally to her.
>
> “I don’t have to put out too much to be dramatic,” she said.
>
> “I always liked it (drama).”
>
> Sadia enjoys comedy, saying, “you have to make people laugh in these
>   serious times.”
>
> Getting involved in varying aspects of the arts, Sadia entered and won
>   Miss India T&T in 2005.
>
> **“Yeah, yeah! Big thing,”** she said with a laugh.
>
> In 2006, she was a finalist in the Best Village competition, copping
>   the Best Talent award for a monologue titled Cultural Changes.
>
> She is also the lead actress for the Princess Town Theatre Workshop.
>
> As busy as she is, Sadia is convinced she will be involved in drama
>   for a long time.Follow
>
> your
>
> dreams
>
> Sadia believes young people should follow their dreams and their
>   passion. She said many young people follow a career their parents want
>   them to,
>
> which may make them
>
> unhappy.
>
> — [Source](http://legacy.guardian.co.tt/archives/2008-10-05/features1.html)

This seems a quite formal interview but can the expression *yeah, big thing* be used ironically in some other situations to indicate the opposite?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The term "big thing" could be used ironically, but its use here is unrelated to the tone of the writing because it occurs in a quote. There's nothing in particular in this piece to indicate how Sadia intends the term "big thing" to be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost anything can be used ironically if you try hard enough. :)

It's certainly possible that "yeah, big thing" is ironic here, but the interview doesn't give enough context to decide for sure.